# sort and filter a text file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have the below text file - basefile.txt.

```
No|ID|Order|Yes/No|script
1|A|1|Yes|a.sh
2|B|2|Yes|b.sh
3|C|3|No|c.sh
4|E|5|Yes|e.sh
5|D|4|Yes|d.sh
```

I have to sort the above file based on the column "Order" in ascending and retain only those records which have Yes in "Yes/No" column. my intermediate expected output will be like below.

```
No|ID|Order|Yes/No|script
1|A|1|Yes|a.sh
2|B|2|Yes|b.sh
5|D|4|Yes|d.sh
4|E|5|Yes|e.sh
```

Now, I have to execute all the shell scripts in the above intermediate output with ID as parameter one by one.

```
./a.sh A
./b.sh B
./d.sh D
./e.sh E
```

is there a way to do this in shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need

```
#! /bin/bash

textFile=$1

sed '/|No|/d' $textFile > newFile.txt
sort -k 3 -n newFile.txt --field-separator="|" > newFile2.txt

rm newFile.txt


while IFS='|' read -r No ID Order YesNo script ; do

./$script $ID
 
done < newFile2.txt

rm newFile2.txt
```

Your text file should be following:

```
1|A|1|Yes|a.sh
2|B|2|Yes|b.sh
3|C|3|No|c.sh
4|E|5|Yes|e.sh
5|D|4|Yes|d.sh
```

You can run the script with

```
./shell.sh textFileName.txt
```

Don't forget to give permission all .sh files

Comment: Let me know if doesn't work if it works please mark it as an answer, Thank you

Comment: Sure.. will check and mark it

Comment: Here you are modifying the $textFile. Can we do that without modifying it. We can work with the new file.txt and then remove it finally ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229716/discussion-between-yusuf-sengun-and-padfoot123).